# Как стилизовать выбранный элемент в ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть элемент `ListBox`

```
        <ListBox Name="PurchaseList"
             Width="400"
             Height="102"
             Margin="60,10,61,10"
             BorderThickness="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             SelectionChanged="PurchaseList_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Width="{Binding ElementName=PurchaseList,
                                       Path=Width}"
                       Height="31"
                       BorderBrush="Black"
                       BorderThickness="1"
                       Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

При выборе элемента меняю триггером стили - все меняется кроме фона подсветки, она так и остается стандартной синей. Как это исправить?

Comment: Судя по всему, вам нужно не Selected, а Focused. (Голубой фон обозначает элемент с фокусом, по идее.) Вот как устроен шаблон по умолчанию: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx (ищите `<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">` и смотрите на Template). В крайнем случае вам придётся просто переопределить Template на свой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве быстрого хака, попробуйте подменить цвет таким образом:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                     Color="HotPink"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                     Color="PowderBlue" />
</ListBox.Resources>
```

Это решение пользуется тем, что в моей версии WPF для элемента с фокусом используется цвет по ключу `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey`. В других версиях это может быть не так, поэтому более правильным будет решение с переопределением `Tempalte`'а  в `ItemContainerStyle`.

---

Честный способ — переопределение `ItemContainerStyle`. Он довольно громоздкий. В качестве отправной точки можно брать стиль, указанный [в документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), и подправить его:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".35"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".55" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".75"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="contentPresenter"
                            Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Вас интересует строчка с `<Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2"`. Например:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Opacity="0" Fill="HotPink" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
```

Внимательно глядя на определение из документации, видно, почему переопределение `Background` на триггере не сработало.

Вы можете всегда подсмотреть стиль, который использует ваша система, при помощи Expression Blend'а (он умеет прочитать системный стиль и сделать из него XAML-определение, которое потом можно подправить и использовать).

Comment: Ну да работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @RussCoder: Пожалуйста! Дополнил ответ.