# Как сменить цвет выделения в ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Как сменить цвет выделения элемента в ListBox?

Вот мой Xaml код ListBox`а:

```
         <ListBox Grid.Row="0" 
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 Opacity="0.8"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Radios}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRadio}"
                 BorderThickness="0">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Margin="5" Opacity="1"
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               IsItemsHost="True">
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel >
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
                               Width="200"
                               Height="150">
                            </Image>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Name }">
                            </Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

В интернете нашел вот такой вот способ `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myLBStyle}"`, но он у меня не сработал:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myLBStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="Red"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Где-то точно было, неоднократно. Поищите по тегу [tag:wpf].

Comment: Например: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460879/10105

Comment: @VladD, Разобрался, спасибо!

Comment: Отлично, тогда можно закрывать как дубликат?

Comment: Да, можно закрывать.