# Как поменять задний фон выбраного елемента listbox avalonia ui

Tags: c#, xaml, avalonia

у меня есть view с listbox снизу код  я не знаю как мне зделать так что бы убрать синие подсвечивание выбраного елемента

```xml
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AvaloniaMain.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="1920" d:DesignHeight="1080"
             x:Class="AvaloniaMain.Views.MainView"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">
    <Design.DataContext>
   
    <vm:MainViewModel />
  </Design.DataContext>
    
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,*,Auto">
  <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="85"  ColumnDefinitions="300,200,200,*,120,120">
<Grid  ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto" Grid.Column="0">
        <Border IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}" CornerRadius="7" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="4">
            <Grid Height="60" Margin="3" RowDefinitions="*,*" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
              <Label  HorizontalAlignment="Center" >Скарбничка:</Label>                          
              <Label Grid.Row="1" >Сума Бонусів:</Label>
              <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding UserMoneyBox}"></TextBlock>
              <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding UserMoneyBonus}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>      
        </Border>
        <Border  IsVisible="{Binding Visibility }"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Image  Height="60"  Width="100" Source="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"></Image>
      </Border>
      </Grid>
       <Button Background="#e0e0e0" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Height="60" CornerRadius="15">
         <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Видача картки</Label>
       </Button>
       <Button  Background="#e0e0e0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="1" Width="200" Height="60" CornerRadius="15">
         <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Видача картки</Label>
       </Button>
       <Button Command="{Binding ChangeColorCommand}" Background="{Binding ButtonColor}" Grid.Column="4" Margin="2" Width="120" Height="60" CornerRadius="15">
       <Image Source="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"></Image>
       </Button>
      <Button  Background="#e0e0e0"  Grid.Column="5" Margin="2" Width="120" Height="60" CornerRadius="15">
      <Image Source="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"></Image>
       </Button>
    </Grid>

 <Rectangle Height="4" Fill="Green" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ></Rectangle>
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
    <!-- Заголовок -->
    <Border Background="#C1FFC1">
         <Grid ColumnDefinitions="1110,100,285,130,130,160">
             <Border  Height="40"  Grid.Column="0">
                                  <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"   FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Назва</Label>
             </Border>
       <Border    Grid.Column="2">
                                  <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"   FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Кількість</Label>

             </Border>
               <Border    Height="40"  Grid.Column="3">
                                  <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"   FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Вага</Label>

             </Border>
           <Border  Height="40"  Grid.Column="4">
                                  <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"   FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Ціна</Label>

             </Border>
                   <Border  Height="40"  VerticalAlignment=""   Grid.Column="5">
                                  <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"   FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Всього</Label>

             </Border>
       
      </Grid>
    </Border>



     <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RecieptPosition}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecieptPosition}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Border Grid.Column="0" Height="120" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
        <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Height="30" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>



  </StackPanel>










  <Grid Grid.Row="3" Background="Gray" Height="50" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto"></Grid>
         


  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

[image]

вот как это выглядит именно выбранный елемент подсвечивает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460879/220553